# SVG syntax error

Tags: svg

The following code does not render the white text. I wish for the white text to render:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="200" height="200">
    <text id="e1_texte" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px;" y="40" x="4" 
      fill="white">
  Please display me
  </text>
</rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text doesn't belong inside a `<rect>` element. Move it outside:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="200" height="200">
</rect>
    <text id="e1_texte" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px;" y="40" x="4" 
      fill="white">
  Please display me
  </text>
</svg>
```